# python, data structures, algorithm: how to rank top 10 most visited pages in latest 60 minutes?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, queue

If there a data structures likes container/queue, based on time , I could use it this way: add item(may duplicate) into it one by one, pop out those added time ealier then 60 minutes; count the queue; then I got top 10 most added items, in a dymatice period, said, 60min.
How to implement this time based container ?

Comment: Sounds like a priority queue https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes

Comment: Put a timer request in user content. Calculate with condition push to pop_up window. But used additional system resource. Or save user page inside and push data to any where.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Start timer 60 minutes
2. Get the pages that people visits
3. Save pages
4. If timer is not ended do step 2-3 again if timed is ended:
   Count wich one is the most visited
   Count wich one is the second most visited
   Etc